# IOS create PDF file with rotation text

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

I create pdf file. I need to draw rotation text. In current time I have this pdf file

[image]

My code which draw the text

```
............

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, frameRect.origin.y*2);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
// Draw the frame.
CTFrameDraw(frame, context);


// Add these two lines to reverse the earlier transformation.
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, (-1)*frameRect.origin.y*2);
```

I know that I must use `CGContextRotateCTM(CGContextRef c, GFloat angle)`, but I bad understand transformation and I can't do as I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following adds text rotated -90 degrees to the specified context at the yOffset from the top of the page:

```
+(void)addRotatedLabel:(CGContextRef)context atYOffset:(CGFloat)yOffset{

    // -90 degrees
    CGFloat rotation = -M_PI / 2.f;
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, rotation);

    NSString *label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"some text"];
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(300, 12);
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:7.5f];
    CGSize textSize = [label sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping];
    CGRect titleRect = CGRectMake(-yOffset, 32.f - textSize.height + 3.f, textSize.width, textSize.height);

    [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
    [label drawInRect:titleRect withFont:font];

    CGContextRotateCTM(context, -rotation);
}
```

It can be easily modified to handle other rotations, font sizes, pass in the `NSString`, etc.